# How to make different session/proxy with each request?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to make something like round-robin(each request different proxy/session) implementation. So, I have code example in Golang:

```
// Round Robin algorithm implementation
func RoundRobin(proxies ...string) func(*http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    var urls []*url.URL
    for _, proxy := range proxies {
        u, err := url.Parse(proxy)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        urls = append(urls, u)
    }

    var mu sync.Mutex
    var i, lenUrls int = 0, len(urls)
    return func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        mu.Lock()
        i = (i + 1) % lenUrls
        u := urls[i]
        mu.Unlock()
        return u, nil
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to do the same in Python:

```
import concurrent.futures
from itertools import cycle 
import requests

def each_req(url):
        proxy = cycle(
            [
                'http://209.50.52.162:9050', 
                'http://209.50.52.162:9050',
            ]
        )
        # each reqeust should be different proxy
        requests.get(url, proxy=next(proxy))

    
tasks = [
            "www.example.com",
            "www.google.com",
        ]


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(each_req, url): url for url in tasks}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            print(future.result())
```

Be honestly, I dont know how to make it correct

**P.S.** This is how to run sync:

```
def each_req():
    proxy = cycle(
        [
            "http://209.50.52.162:9050",
            "http://150.50.52.162:9050",
        ]
    )
    for _ in range(10):
        print(next(proxy))

each_req()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will be useful for someone

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import requests

from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep


def do_requests(proxi, url):
    print(url, proxi)
    r = requests.get(
        url,
        proxies=dict(http=proxi),
    )
    print(r.text)


def round_robin():
    proxy = [
        "socks5://proxy",
        "socks5://proxy",,
        "socks5://proxy",,
    ]

    for _ in range(1):
        random.shuffle(proxy)

    round_proxy = cycle(proxy)

    targets = [
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
        "http://www.example.com",
    ]

    tasks = list(zip(round_proxy, targets))
    # print(tasks)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
        future_to_url = {
            executor.submit(do_requests, proxy, source): (proxy, source)
            for proxy, source in tasks
        }
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            future.result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(10):
        round_robin()
        print("=>" * 20)
```